# Responsive canvas and fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have created a website to allow users to design playing cards online using fabricjs and have made the canvas responsive so it will work equally well on mobile devices as desktop.  Almost everything works perfect... On smaller screens the objects are scaled correctly with the canvas and positioned correctly based on the canvas size but selecting/manipulating the objects doesn't work properly.  When the canvas is scaled down from it's original (desktop based) size I cannot click on the object.  I have noticed that the point on the canvas you need to click to select the object is shifted down and right from the object itself.  The smaller the canvas gets, the further from the object the selection point gets.  Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!
Steve Sherrin

Comment: did you find any solution ever?